# How i do dual boot?

Tags: grub2, 15.10

So I had Windows 7 installed on my computer and I installed Ubuntu on a different partition and now it boots me directly to Ubuntu (after installing it) and I want to have a dual boot option!

How I do it? Do I need to use GRUB? And how that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed Grub during Ubuntu installation.
You need to add windows as a boot entry for you.

Use Boot-Repair to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Grub does not recognize the windows partition. Go to terminal and press:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -2):

When you install ubuntu you need to choose the "Something else" option and the configure the swap area (wich will allow you to choose to boot ubuntu or windows), and it's that simple ;)

Comment: That isn't what swap is for, there will be an "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option, and this question is a duplicate.